# ios - I have the crash code and the .dSYM file, but how to get the place where the crash happened?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, symbolicatecrash

I have this symbolicated crash report from Apple:

```
Thread 0:
14  Fundraising                     0x0007a3aa 0x79000 + 5034
```

And I have the binary archived in my organizer archives.  But I don't really understand what steps are needed to "decode" that symbolicated code. Would someone be able to please explain the steps to me that are needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this if you have the .dSYM files also archived with the binary

http://sourceforge.net/p/umsservices/wiki/Home/

it should do the job for you.